# .htaccess clean url to GET variable with WordPress

Tags: htaccess, redirects, wordpress

I'm struggling to get a `.htaccess` rule to work. I'm trying to cleanup a URL for a WordPress site. Instead of `/illustration?rid=123`, I'd like `/illustration/123`.

I've tried solutions from many of the other threads on this site, but still not able to get it to work. The current code I am using is:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^illustration/(.*)$ /illustration?rid=$1 [QSA]
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You need to do this in WordPress itself, with its internal URL rewriting system - not `.htaccess`. The problem here is that WordPress routes URLs based on the `REQUEST_URI` PHP server variable, which contains `/illustration/123`, not the rewritten URL. (I'm assuming this URL should be routed through WordPress?)

Comment: @MrWhite Thanks for that. Do you think it is possible to do a redirect instead?

Comment: @MrWhite I managed to get a solution working using RedirectMatch. Thanks for your help

Comment: Glad you got a solution. Please post your solution as an answer (you can later accept it) to remove the question from the unanswered question queue. Thanks. (Although you should generally avoid using mod_alias `Redirect` / `RedirectMatch` directives together with mod_rewrite, since the mod_rewrite directives execute first, despite the order of directives in the config file.)